# Can not deserialize instance of object out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, spring, post

i want to send my user to server and get a Long number as response but i got 400 error on client and got this exeption at server side:

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of mashfood.model.User out of START_ARRAY token
```

my client sUser model is completely same as server User model:

sUser(or User):

```
class User{
public long id;

public String username;

public String password;

public String firstName;

public String lastName;

public String gender;

public String nationalNumber;

public String phoneNumber;

public String address;

public String email;

public boolean isLoggedIn;

public String imageUrl;

public int areaNumber;

}
```

client connect to server like this:
** tClass is class type of response
** params[0] is user that i want to send to server
** url+conditions is url of method that handle getting user

```
protected ResponseHandler doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        serverResponse=new ServerResponse();
        result = restTemplate.postForObject(URL + conditions, params,tClass);
        serverResponse.singleResult=result;
        serverResponse.isReady=true;
        responseHandler.onServerRespond(serverResponse);
    }catch (Exception e){
        serverResponse.isReady=false;
        serverResponse.message=e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return responseHandler;
}
```

and server side code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Long registerNewUser(@RequestBody User user){
    if(user!=null){
        try {
            System.out.println("REGISTER "+ user==null);
            SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibenateConnection.connectingHibernate();
            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            User user1=getUser(user.username);
            session.close();
            return user1.id;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return -1l;
}
```

and my output JSON is:

```
[{
"address": "",
"areaNumber": 0,
"email": "email",
"firstName": "name",
"gender": "male",
"id": -1,
"imageUrl": "img",
"isLoggedIn": false,
"lastName": "lastn",
"nationalNumber": "898898",
"password": "pass",
"phoneNumber": "936",
"username": "mehdi"
}]
```

where is my problem?

Comment: Can you please post the JSON string ?

Comment: @Bhokal yes i added to my question

Comment: Why is this vote closed as off-topic? It contains a MCVE.

Comment: @mehdiakbarian probably was in error, I voted to re-open it and others agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my client JSON output is in form of List of User that contain One User and i Change server register method like this to solve my problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean registerNewUser(@RequestBody List<User> users){
    if(users!=null){
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibenateConnection.connectingHibernate();
            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(users.get(0));
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```